# Breeze with knockoutjs nested foreach: can't find third level data

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm using John Papa's excellent SPA example using Breeze and Knockout to display a data graph.  It's mostly working but I'm stuck at an array that I can't seem to list out in a foreach loop.

Here's my data-graph:
[image: DataGraph]

I'm fine up to the Fees array.

Here's the knockout markup:

```
        <div id="memberships" class="span9">
      <div class="span8">Memberships</div>
      <div class="span9 table-bordered" data-bind="foreach: memberships()">
        <span class="span5" data-bind="text: organization().name()"></span> <span class="span3" data-bind="text: '    Status:' + status().description()"></span>
        <div class="label-important span2" data-bind="text: 'Dues paid:'"></div>
        <div class="span5" data-bind="text: 'dues count:' + fees().length,  foreach: fees()">
          <div data-bind="text: 'Method:' + payMethod()"></div>
          <div data-bind="text: receivedOn()"></div>
          <div data-bind="text: membershipYear()"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I can see the organization().name() and status().description() but get zero for the length of fees().

I've looked at other answers for this kind of issue in knockout foreach loops and the issue seems to be in whether the array is an observableArray.  However, in this situation Breeze is setting this up so I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong or Breeze is.

Here's the breeze EntityQuery:

```
  var getPhysicianDetails = function (physicianObservable) {
    var id = physicianObservable().id();
    var query = EntityQuery.from('Physicians')
      .expand(
        "ContactInfo.Emails.Scope, " +
        "ContactInfo.Phones.Scope, " +
        "ContactInfo.Addresses.Scope," +
        "PhysicianSpecialties.Specialty, " +
        "PhysicianNotes, " +
        "Memberships.Organization, " +
        "Memberships.Status," +
        "Memberships.Fees.PayNotes," +
        "IncentivePrograms.Notes," + 
        "PhysInOrgs.Organization, " +
        "IncentivePrograms.IncentiveProgram.Payer," +
        "PhysicianPayers.Payer"
        )
      .where("id", "==", id);
```

When I do a getEntityType("Fee") I get this (from Chrome Dev's Watch Expressions):

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your browser console are there any binding erorrs?

Comment: Yes, I've looked for binding errors but there are none.  The html displays fine even past the level of memberships

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a binding error for using the text and foreach bindings on the same element. *(Multiple bindings (text and foreach) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element.;)*

You could change this:

```
<div class="span5" data-bind="text: 'dues count:' + fees().length,  foreach: fees()">
      <div data-bind="text: 'Method:' + payMethod()"></div>
      <div data-bind="text: receivedOn()"></div>
      <div data-bind="text: membershipYear()"></div>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="span5">
    <div data-bind="text: 'dues count:' + fees().length"></div>

     <!-- ko foreach: fees -->
         <div data-bind="text: 'Method:' + payMethod()"></div>
         <div data-bind="text: receivedOn()"></div>
         <div data-bind="text: membershipYear()"></div>
     <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What does your client side query look like?.

I'm guessing that you are missing an expand 'clause' to get to the 'fees' navigation property.

Comment: What do you get when you call MetadataStore.getEntityType("Fee")?

Comment: I've added more to the main body of the question.  Let me know if you want to see more of the feesType variable expanded.  Thanks for your time!